# Bitnami moodle image errors out with dbport not specified

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, moodle, bitnami

This is my docker compose file,

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:latest
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
      - MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET=utf8mb4
      - MARIADB_COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
  moodle:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/moodle:4.3.2
    ports:
      - '7470:8080'
      - '7443:8443'
    environment:
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - BITNAMI_DEBUG=true
      - MOODLE_SITE_NAME=Moodle v3 Test 1
      - MOODLE_USERNAME=foobar_user
      - MOODLE_PASSWORD=something

    volumes:
      - ./moodle:/bitnami/moodle
      - ./moodledata:/bitnami/moodledata
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  moodle_data:
    driver: local
  moodledata_data:
    driver: local
```

I am getting the error, `/opt/bitnami/scripts/libmoodle.sh: line 278: 2: missing database port, moodledeployment-moodle-1 exited with code 1` even when I have specified the port number in the environment variables. How to fix this?
I have tried volume mounting config.php to directly specify the database port in config, but that gives another error, `Config table does not contain the version. You cannot continue.` I did not find a solution to this problem either. (I tried creating the config table myself and adding the version entry, and that gave error reading from database when I tried running bitnami moodle container)